# find folder where a file is located

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, odoo

I just installed odoo from ubuntu downloaded from microsoft store, but I can't find the folder that was created. The command to be created is

```
git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 12.0 / mnt / c / odoo
```

however, when going to the directory there is no folder but I run odoo. Could you help me find the folder please. It should be noted that when executing odoo it mentions that it was executed from

```
 / home / fcogm / mnt / c / odoo /
```

Comment: Please run command `locate odoo/__manifest__.py` and share the result.

Comment: when executing I jump to another line to put another command nothing more than that